# When to use compression

Tags: hadoop, serialization, compression

The question is in the title - when is it good to use compression? By good I meen faster processing.

My pipeline consists of multiple MR jobs and intermediate results are stored in sequence files.

The data is numeric - time series. Also, it happens that output of one job has same size as the input. So, the data transfered/stored can be large.

I would like to know whether I can expect speedup due to compression, or it will take more time to compress/decompress data?

Answer (score 0):

It is almost always a good idea to enable compression of intermediate data with a fast codec (read snappy). You won't get penalized too much even if your data is uncompressible.

Answer (score 0):

Compression doesn't affect your job as long as you are aware what you are trying to achieve, make sure your compressed data is splittable. I found bzip2 format more convenient with compression ratio and CPU usages but better to do in-house testing with different formats on your data set.

Compression give two major benefits.

1) use less disk space while running mapreduce job (intermittent output and final output compressed).
2) Increase job performance since we are sending compressed data during shuffling phase across the cluster nodes.

Hope that will help.